# 2 line li menu items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My code is as follows :

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href=""> Custom Decor</a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Home Exterior </a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Cleaning Services </a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Heating & Cooling </a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Parts, Repair & Maintanence </a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Energy Effeciency </a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Sears Telecom </a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Protection Agreements </a></li>
</ul>
```

What I have is -- [image]

**What I want is --**

-Decor below Custom

-Exterior under Home

-Services under Cleaning , etc.

Something like this [image]

two lines, 2 words .. How do I do this in CSS?

Comment: http://qrayg.com/experiment/cssmenus/

Comment: should the second row be visible all the time?

Comment: With row, I assume you mean the 2nd "line" of text .. YES, it should

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you two solutions (second recomended):

- Insert `<br />` into your text, where new line should be inserted, or
- Specify in CSS width of your item, and put `&nbsp;` between the words which should appear in one line.

Comment: should I specify the width to `li` item?

Comment: In my opinion, that would be the best option.